# Inserting after the last record (bottom) shown in DBGrid

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

What should be the code for inserting after the last record using the ClientDataSet?

I tried the following:

```
cdsSomething.Last;
cdsSomething.Insert:
```

But it appears it replaces the last record instead. I am sure there must be a quick code for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method to append a record to the end of the Dataset (let alone any index) is `Append`. You don't even need to call `Last` before.

```
cdsSomething.Append;
```

`Insert` inserts a row before the selected record, so with your code, the new record should become the second to last record.

Comment: @GolezTrol: All movements like Next, Prev, First, Last internally call CheckBrowseMode, which makes sure that any changes are saved before doing the movement.

Comment: I knew it! There's really quick code for this. Though, when I use this through a TButton, it focused to the new line below first column but I still have to click it with my mouse to be able to enter data. This is minor issue but if there is a one-click for this the better. Meaning, upon appending I could straight away type the data.

Comment: Seems like the button steals the focus from the grid. Try calling `<NameOfTheGrid>.SetFocus;` after the call to `Append`.

Comment: Perfect! @UweRaabe Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

In general, where an added record (or, in fact, any record) appears in the DBGrid does not depend on the dataset operations which were used to insert it.

In fact, the DBGrid is irrelevant to this question, because it simply displays the added row in the ClientDataSet in the position the added row occurs in the CDS according to its current index order.

So, for example, if the CDS contains an integer ID field, and its current index is this ID field (e.g. because the CDS's IndexFieldNames property is set to 'ID'), to make the added row appear at the end, all you need to do is to set its ID value to something higher than any existing record in the CDS.  If the field is of type `ftAutoInc`, this will, of course, happen automatically.

Uwe Raabe has answered this q a bit differently.  What he says is correct if the CDS is not using any index, so the records are displayed in the physical order they appear in the CDS's datafile.  However, relying on the physical order to determine the display order is not necessarily a good idea if the display order is important.  If it is, then use an indexed field (or fields) to determine the order.

Comment: Thank you for your views. I am not actually using any index for now. I will remember this in case in the future I need one. I am sure, I will come across with this.