# What is the difference between TDataSet.Insert and TDataSet.Append?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

These two code samples appear to do the same thing, is there any difference between them in terms of the way the data is added to the database?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADOTable1.Append;
  ADOTable1['Name'] := 'Mike';
  ADOTable1.Post;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADOTable1.Insert;
  ADOTable1['Name'] := 'Mike';
  ADOTable1.Post;
end;
```

Comment: You might have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927417).  TAdoTable relies on the ADO layer, which may not follow the same rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TDataSet.Insert Method - Inserts a new, empty record in the dataset =>

- http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DB_TDataSet_Insert.html

TDataSet.Append Method - Adds a new, empty record to the end of the dataset =>

- http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DB_TDataSet_Append.html